# How can I download multiple files stored in a text file with curl and xargs?

Tags: curl, xargs

How can I download multiple files stored in a text file with curl and xargs?
This is my last trial:

```
cat listfile.txt | xargs curl -O
```

first file works well, but other files are just output to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution:

```
cat ./../c | xargs -n1 curl -O
```

xargs splits stdin by spaces and newlines, and passes to curl at once.
So curl called only once with long arguments.

`n1` option limits this passing argument count as 1, so curl will be called multiple times.

Answer (score 12):

Using GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ you can do:

```
cat listfile.txt | parallel curl -O
```

Not only does GNU Parallel deal nicely with special chars like ' " and space, you will also get the added benefit of downloading in parallel.

Watch the intro video to GNU Parallel: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Nice suggestion. But I have no time ti test this, so +1, and thanks!

Comment: This is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

xargs doesn't know what curl is so it can't determine how many arguments it should pass in one round. So the solution is to pass a -n1 option to it as you mentioned.